# Is my solution correct? (primes of the form $a^2+b^2d$ and their principal ideals)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm interested in the following exercise:

> A prime integer might be of the form $a^2 + b^2d$, with $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$.
>   Discuss carefully how this is related to the prime factorization of
>   $(p)$ in $R$.

Here $R:=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-d)$ is an *imaginary* quadratic field (i.e. $d<0$ is square free). **Also I believe there is a typo and it's meant to be $a^2-b^2d$.**

---

**My attempt:**

As $p=(a+b \sqrt{-d})(a-b \sqrt{-d})$ we find

$$(p)=(a+b \sqrt{-d})(a-b \sqrt{-d}) $$

where the parentheses stand for "the principal ideal generated by...". This shows that $(p)$ is not a prime ideal in $R$, which leaves us with two possibilities:

1. There exists a prime ideal $P < R$ such that $(p)=P \overline{P}$ (i.e. $p$ splits in $R$)
2. There exists a prime ideal $P < R$ such that $(p)=PP$ (i.e. $p$ is ramified in $R$).

One can see that $p$ ramifies if and only if $(a+b \sqrt{-d})=(a-b \sqrt{-d})$, which happens when they are associates (i.e. one is a unit times the other). Now let us quote the following result

> The units of $R$ are $\{ \pm 1\}$ unless $d=-1$ or $d=-3$. In the former they are $\{\pm 1, \pm \sqrt{-1}\}$ and in the latter the group of sixth roots of unity.

It is clear that if $d \notin \{-1,-3\}$ $a \pm b \sqrt{-d}$ cannot be associates. Let us look at the cases $d=-1$ and $d=-3$ separately:

- If $d=-1$, we might have $a+bi=\pm i (a-bi)$ (the other units don't work). It turns out this happens iff $a= \pm b$, or that $p=a^2+a^2(1)=2a^2$. Obviously the only such prime is $p=2$.
- If $d=-3$, we check whether $a+b \sqrt{-3}=\rho_6^k (a-b\sqrt{-3})$ where $\rho_6=\exp{2 \pi i/6}$ and $k \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\} \setminus \{0,3\}$.

  The case $k=1$ gives $a=3b$, and $p=9b^2+3b^2=12b^2$ which is not a prime.

  The case $k=2$ gives $a=b$, and $p=a^2+3 a^2=4a^2$ which is not a prime.

  The case $k=4$ gives $a=-b$, and $p=4a^2$ again which is not a prime.

  The case $k=5$ gives $a=-3b$ and $p=12b^2$, which is not a prime.

To summarize:

If $p$ is an integer prime of the form $a^2+b^2|d|$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$,  it splits in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-d}]$, unless $d=-1$ and $p=2$.

---

**My questions:**

- Am I wrong with the typo in the beginning? Does he really mean the *difference* of a square and a square times $|d|$?
- Since elements in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ also have the form $a+b \sqrt{-3}$ where $a,b \in \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z} \setminus\mathbb{Z}$, I'm afraid the author might have wanted me to include the case $p=3=(3 \times \frac{1}{2})^2+3 (\frac{1}{2})^2$ which comes from $k=1$ and $k=5$. Is this right?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that $a \pm b\sqrt{-d}$ can be associates in a not completely trivial way, i.e. if $a = 0$ and $b = \pm 1$, which can only happen if $p = -d$. Therefore, there's an extra case where $p$ ramifies, i.e. in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-p}]$.

Comment: (Also, the similar problem (which only asks you to deal with the case $p \equiv 2, 3 \pmod 4$) in the 2nd edition of Artin has $a^2 - b^2 d$, so I believe this was a typo in the 1st edition.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]\cong \mathbb{Z}[t]/(t^2-d)$ where $d$ is square free, then the standard norm is $N(x+y\sqrt{d})=(x+y\sqrt{d})(x-y\sqrt{d})=x^2-y^2d$. Since the author takes negative $d$, he might meant that the ring is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$ where $d$ is positive (and $-d$ is negative), and then the norm is $x^2+dy^2$.

For your second question, the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ has only the elements $a+b\sqrt{-3}$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$. This ring is strictly contained in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})}=\mathbb{Z}[\frac {1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}]$, which I think is what you meant.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed that's what I meant. $R$ should be taken to be the ring of algebraic integers.